# Run Flask on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2

I have built an EC2 instance on AWS amazon.
I upload my Flask server.py on EC2 when I run it returns this message "Serving on [http://0.0.0.0:8080"](http://0.0.0.0:8080%22)
But I did not get any response when accessing the route. I use postman to connect API here the results I run on localhost
[image]

when I run on my EC2 it is not response anything. I try to change Ip address of EC2 instance but it is not working, can anyone help me. thank you very much.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are security groups for the instance?

Comment: Can you tag the NGINX, Apache?

Comment: I set default security groups

Comment: Are you literally trying to connect to `http://0.0.0.0:8080`?
That's not the IP of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, my advice will help you. If you put the public IP address of your EC2 instance with port 8080 (by default for Flask) it's going to open the flask app in the browser(for example 53.25.25.45/8080, where 53...45 is your EC2 IP Address). Also, check your Security Group, what's your Ingress rule are? If you didn't specify port 8080 (by selecting custom TCP rule) then it's not going to work. Make sure, SSH (port 22), HTTP (port 8080 custom TCP ) and other ports are open which required by your application.

For more refer to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html

Comment: I set like this but it still does not work

Comment: could you share the SG and Error output?